# Typescript - ReturnType of functions in an interface

Tags: typescript, types

One thing I'm really struggling to understand is how to write a function that takes a key of a particular interface, and returns the value with the correct type. Something like the following:

```
interface Transformers {
  boolean: (value: string) => boolean;
  string: (value: string) => string;
}

const transformers: Transformers = {
  boolean: (value) => Boolean(value),
  string: (value) => value,
}

function transformValue<T extends keyof Transformers>(value: string, type: T): ReturnType<Transformers[T]> {
  return transformers[type](value);
}
```

Here, I would expect that if I pass in `transformValue('lorem', 'boolean')` I would get a boolean back, and if I pass in `transformValue('lorem', 'string')` I would get a string. But I'm getting the error `Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Transformers[T]>'` and I can't work out why.

[Here is a TS Playground link if it helps.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpTiAzjA9lAW2i2QG8AoZZAI11wBsJMAuZACgDc56BXCVrGCigA5gEpkAXgB8NOo0wBuSskHCQI1p258BQ0RJmr9G5QF9y5BLmxhkQzDnxEoWVukd5CxKWRW0GJhAtLl4IQ1kAIXkg7TCxABoVNVEQnXCpWVC%20JItyGB4QBDBgG3sMbC8CADV0gB5UZAgAD0gQABMSAGsIAE9cGDQKp29XaTjdY3URBPtegAd%20NDFWACUIMB4oEFQFiAbhquIAbVQAXVkKKigNrZByz2cTsD2zifDzciA)

Comment: TS can't do arbitrary higher-order analysis on generic conditional types, such as  seeing  how `ReturnType<Transformers[T]>` relates to `T` when `T` is generic.  If you want to support this you need to refactor as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXgkJW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find an appropriate dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes this answers the question thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the type checker isn't smart enough to understand the abstract relationship between [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` and `ReturnType<Transformers[T]>`.  [The `ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and TypeScript is notoriously unable to do much analysis on generic conditional types.  It tends to defer evaluation of such types, leaving them as opaque black boxes.

The recommended refactoring is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Instead of using conditional types, we write a "base" mapping interface, and then express all our operations as generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  In your example that looks like this:

```
interface TypeMap {
  boolean: boolean;
  string: string;
}

type Transformers =
  { [K in keyof TypeMap]: (value: string) => TypeMap[K] }

const transformers: Transformers = {
  boolean: (value) => Boolean(value),
  string: (value) => value,
}

function transformValue<K extends keyof Transformers>(value: string, type: K): TypeMap[K] {
  return transformers[type](value); // okay
}
```

That works because inside `transformValue`, the type of `transformers[type]` can be readily interpreted as a single function of type `(value: string) => TypeMap[K]`.  Note that this interpretation only happens because `Transformers` is itself a mapped type over `TypeMap`.  If you left your original definition, the type would be equivalent, but the compiler would have no idea how to maintain the relationship between `transformers[type]` and `K`, and you'd end up with a useless [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions like `((value: string) => boolean) | ((value: string) => string)`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMsgEYD2lANhHCAFwXV0MDcpyAzmFKAHNmvfiAGcAvsWJgsKVFAbcYlKAFto3ZAF4uhZAG0A0slDIA1hHSUYaOXkwBdZgAoAbnBoBXCML6CASh0APjtsB2NHZCliBEoQXmQ+JRV1TWYFFNUNKC1tIi4qWnomZHdPHyDtUIAhVhLy7wgAgBouEUFXDyaq0O6fNpiYLxAEMGB4pMUE1LUANQqIAB4TCAAPSBAAEy1La1tMmezNYMafP1EBFqS5ZiMAjPt8SIKyKAgwLygQKay03IMsmwjjOzUkxCAA)